# Repair Corrupted Save or Restart New Game Plus

Tags: pc, batman-arkham-origins

I finished the first story play through in `Arkham Origins` and was moving along in `New Game Plus` when, after retrieving the Disruptor from the GCPD, I come out of the morgue and end up as Batman in Space:

[image]

Unfortunately, at this point the game decides to save so my checkpoint is hosed.

Is there any way to fix this corrupted save? Or is there any way to delete just the progress in `New Game Plus` and start it over (without losing all my progress from the initial playthrough)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem at a different point in the game.

On a Steam forum, someone recommended doing the following, and it worked for me.

- Load the game, but instead of continuing the story, choose to do
  one of the challenges with Deathstroke (I'm not sure if it matters or
  not, but it's what he recommended, and it's what I did).
- After completing the challenge, go back and choose to continue the story.
- At this point, the same problem might still be occurring (it was
  for me), BUT if you pause, and choose to restart at the last
  checkpoint, it clears up.

Comment: Beautiful and brilliant! You, sir, win the internet!